# How to join a public hangout?

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

Before, I could easily join public hangouts. But now, whenever I click on the play button it's opening a Youtube live stream.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A hangout is indeed a public live stream video that is shown on Youtube, are you mistaking it for something else?

***Edit:*** What you are seeing on that page is called *Hangouts on Air*. You can't join such hangouts, only watch them. You can, however, join public hangouts that don't do any broadcasting.

Comment: they're suppose to be joinable.

Comment: Yeah, you can join public hangouts if they are not broadcasting any videos. See https://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1349254&topic=1651547&ctx=topic